# How to show the imported csv data into a table using reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, csv

I have an upload button to import only CSV files to my Reactjs application. I can successfully upload the data(CSV) using React file reader but now I want to show the CSV data it into a table. I think this could help me but I cannot understand how to use it https://github.com/marudhupandiyang/react-csv-to-table here. Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from 'react-csv-to-table';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    csvData: ''
  };
}

handleFiles = files => {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
     // Use reader.result
       this.setState({
         csvData: reader.result
       })
     }
   reader.readAsText(files[0]);
}

render() {
return (
    <div>
         <ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes={'.csv'}>
                 <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
          </ReactFileReader>
          <CsvToHtmlTable
               data={this.state.csvData}
               csvDelimiter=","
               tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
           />
   </div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

please help. It's very important to me.

Comment: Could you, please, indent/format your code.

Comment: Did you check your console for error messages?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. I just want to know how to use the that csv data to be put into the table using this link https://github.com/marudhupandiyang/react-csv-to-table which requires the sample data. Now to implement here I need that csv data but I dont understand how to use it outside handleFiles scope.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing several elements. You need to 1) Set the state of your component with the data received by the file reader and 2) render `CsvToHtmlTable` component.

Comment: done making changes. It still not works. Neither it gives me any error.

Comment: @CharlieWeems can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. Be careful when using setState inside a function. This reference will be re-binded to the function scope. Use this instead

```
 handleFiles = files => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      // Use reader.result
      this.setState({
        csvData: reader.result
      })
    }
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  }
```

You can test it here. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/qlj338vnkj

Comment: Now if I wish to change the route and show the table in another component right after uploading the csv, how shall I do it?

Comment: save result in redux

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to show up csv in react table. You can use papaparse

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
```

And then fetch the csv

```
fetchCsv() {
    return fetch('/data/data.csv').then(function (response) {

      let reader = response.body.getReader();
      let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

      return reader.read().then(function (result) {
        return decoder.decode(result.value);
      });
    });
  }
    async getCsvData() {
    let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();
    let results = Papa.parse(csvData, { header: true })
    this.getData(results)

  }
```

https://github.com/manaspandey45/react-csv-data-table